# Trying to prepend route parent URLs in Javascript with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, reduce

I have an array of objects that includes Vue Route Routes. I'm using `reduce()` to get all the routes' object nested properties & works. I was able to get the `path` property, but now I need to prepend the URLs to display it the entire URL of each route.

This is my current code:

```
getAllRoutesDetails() {
  this.outputRouteDetails = routes.reduce(function getRoutes(acc, route) {
    acc.push({
      path: route.path,
      name: route.name,
      component: typeof route.component === 'function' ? route.component.name : route.component,
      meta: route.meta,
    });

    if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
      const children = route.children.reduce(getRoutes, []);
      acc.push(...children);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
},
```

I have tried to pass an argument called `parentPath` with initial value of `null` & then check if it exist & if not store the current path on it & then concatenate it like so:

```
getAllRoutesDetails() {
  this.outputRouteDetails = routes.reduce(function getRoutes(acc, route, parentPath = null) {
    acc.push({
      path: parentPath ? `${parentPath}/${route.path}` : route.path,
      name: route.name,
      component: typeof route.component === 'function' ? route.component.name : route.component,
      meta: route.meta,
    });

    if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
      const children = route.children.reduce(getRoutes, []);
      acc.push(...children);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
},
```

But I get `parentPath` is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also tried this:

```
getAllRoutesDetails() {
  this.outputRouteDetails = routes.reduce(function getRoutes(acc, route, parentPath = null) {
    const fullPath = parentPath ? `${parentPath}/${route.path}` : route.path;
    acc.push({
      path: fullPath,
      name: route.name,
      component: typeof route.component === 'function' ? route.component.name : route.component,
      meta: route.meta,
    });

    if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
      const children = route.children.reduce(getRoutes, fullPath, []);
      acc.push(...children);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
},
```

**EDIT2**

Add a snippet below ⬇︎ and a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r4n0z5pa/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   outputRouteDetails: null,
  originalObject: [
   {
    children: [
     {
      children: [
       {
        path: '/clients',
       }
      ],
      path: '/live',
      // othe props
     }
    ],
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard-live',
    component: 'Tabs'
   }
  ]
  },
 created() {
  this.getAllRoutesDetails();
 },
 methods: {
  getAllRoutesDetails() {
      this.outputRouteDetails = this.originalObject.reduce(function getRoutes(acc, route, parentPath = null) {
        const fullPath = parentPath ? `${parentPath}/${route.path}` : route.path;
        acc.push({
          path: fullPath,
          name: route.name,
          component: typeof route.component === 'function' ? route.component.name : route.component,
          meta: route.meta,
        });

        if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
          const children = route.children.reduce(getRoutes, []);
          acc.push(...children);
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
    },
 }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <table class="routes-visualizer_table table">
      <tr class="routes-visualizer_table_head">
        <th class="table-bordered">Path</th>
        <th class="table-bordered">Name</th>
        <th class="table-bordered">Component</th>
        <th class="table-bordered">Meta</th>
      </tr>
      <tr
        v-for="(outputRouteDetail, i) in outputRouteDetails"
        :key="i"
        class="routes-visualizer_table_body"
      >
        <td class="table-bordered">{{ outputRouteDetail.path }}</td>
        <td class="table-bordered">{{ outputRouteDetail.name }}</td>
        <td class="table-bordered">{{ outputRouteDetail.component }}</td>
        <td class="table-bordered">{{ outputRouteDetail.meta }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to create a working example?

Comment: @PaulMcLoughlin I have added a code sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of the reduce callback is the index, so you can't use that to pass in the parent path. What I'd suggest is converting that method into a recursive function. I've prepared an example based on your code:

(note: I've changed the way you set 'outputRouteDetails' to use the Vue setter method, this will ensure that this property remains reactive and that the template will update when its values change)

```
  methods: {
    getAllRoutesDetails() {
      this.$set(this.$data, 'outputRouteDetails', this.reduceRoutes(this.originalObject));

      console.log(this.outputRouteDetails);
    },

    reduceRoutes (obj, parentPath) {
      return obj.reduce((acc, route) => {
        acc.push(this.getRoute(route, parentPath));

        if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
          parentPath = parentPath ? parentPath+route.path : route.path;
          const children = this.reduceRoutes(route.children, parentPath);
          acc.push(...children);
        }

        return acc;
      }, []);
    },

    getRoute (route, parentPath) {
      const fullPath = parentPath ? `${parentPath}${route.path}` : route.path;

      return {
        path: fullPath,
        name: route.name,
        component: typeof route.component === 'function' ? route.component.name : route.component,
        meta: route.meta,
      };
    }
  }
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/JordanRanson/p0dqLay4/20/